# Devise invitable: Resend custom invitation with token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am using a third party email service to handle all my emails and I am running into an issue when attempting to resend an invitation to a client.

When I attempt to perform the following, there is no `raw_invitation_token` available:

```
  def resendInvitation
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user = User.invite!(email: user.email, location_id: user.location_id) do |u|
      u.skip_invitation = true
    end
    p "TOKEN: #{user.raw_invitation_token}"  # TOKEN IS NIL
    SendNewClientEmail.perform_later(user.id, user.raw_invitation_token)
  end
```

Here's the job that handles the invite:

```
class SendNewClientEmail < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id, token)
    @user = User.find(user_id)

    return unless @user.present? && @user.client.present?

    client = @user.client
    location = @user.location
    email = @user.email

    MailjetService.new(TEMPLATE_ID).send_email(
      location.email,
      email,
      'Welcome!',
      {
        'client_id' => client.try(:id),
        'token' => token
      },
      nil,
      "#{location.name.titleize}"
    )
  end
end
```

How else can I access that token so that the link in the email will work?  Is there another token I can use or some other way this will work?

Comment: Why do you think you need this? The gem already has the feature of resending invitations built in. [Mailjet can be used to send emails with ActionMailer](https://github.com/mailjet/mailjet-gem#send-emails-with-actionmailer).

Comment: That's an interesting solution.  I've always used their API but I could wire it up this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the user is already created. Based on the [Document Reference](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable#label-Sending+an+invitation+after+user+creation)

Please try the following

user = User.find(:id)

user.invite!({ skip_invitation: true }, current_user)  # current user is optional to set the invited_by attribute

You can also do this if you have added :skip_invitation to attributes hash if skip_invitation is added to attr_accessible.

User.invite!(skip_invitation: true)

When skip_invitation is used, you must also set the invitation_sent_at field when the user is sent their token. Failure to do so will yield an “Invalid invitation token” error when the user attempts to accept the invite.

Comment: I'll accept this.  The trick was to use the `user.invite` rather than `User.invite` and then everything worked as expected.

Comment: Thank @JeremyThomas. Happy to help.